# Ansible, how to trust certificates?

Tags: ssl, svn, ansible, openssl

Im using the following from svn module:

```
- subversion: 
    repo: https://subversion:80/repos/xt_tools/
    dest: ~/.build/xt_tools
```

I am getting this error: "Server certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted (https://subversion:80)"

As these are VMs (CentOS/7) i spin up as needed, this is a problem i will continually run into.  Im thinking there must be a way to either automatically generate a certificate or auto accept when prompted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would think it's either that you add those CA certs to the machine's trust store, or use the [`executable:`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.9/lib/ansible/modules/source_control/subversion.py#L270) option to point to a custom script that runs `svn` along with providing the [`--trust-server-cert-failures=unknown-ca,cn-mismatch,other`](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#svn-trust) or whatever is appropriate for your specific CA mismatch. You may even be able to get away with `executable: /path/to/svn --trust-server-cert-failure=and-so-forth` but that depends on the nuances of `self.run_command` so ... try it, I guess?

There seems to be some options that are available via a per-user config file, but given that the subversion documentation is all but abandoned, you'll have to read the source to discover whether `trust-server-cert-failures` is included in that config somewhere

Comment: did try '--non-interactive --trust-server-cert', but that doesn't work w/ the command or shell module.

Comment: ok, well, you asked about the `subversion:` module, so I was trying to work within its parameters, but fine: [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62144479/edit) and update it with your version of subversion and the output from that failed command

Comment: what i ended up doing was basically copying the valid cert info to the svn.ssl.server and svn.simple folders when i configure the new vms.